# How to modify contents of view in mailable class?

Tags: laravel, email, view

**What its about:**

I need to analyze the contents of email before sending out the email to the recipients and maybe replace some string contents with other strings.

**The problem:**

This would be a simple task but the architecture is such that a template file exists at the server level and the email sending process comprises of building the view in mailable class using the data provided by the user and the template that exists. One thing I cannot do is change the template completely for this task.

**Where I was confused:**

Would it be possible to analyze and maybe change the contents of the email at the mailable class or somewhere the mailable class is instantiated? A snippet of my mailable class is shown below:

```
public function build()
{   
    $view = $this->applicationTemplate;
    $data = $this->data;
    $subject = $this->subject;
    return $this->subject($subject)
                ->view($view,$data);

}
```

Would it be possible to change it here before the view and the data gets built? If not, is it possible to change the view once it is instantiated? Cause I used `var_dump` in the $mailable class where it was instantiated and `$mailable->view` showed NULL.

Comment: you want dynamic data in your view file?? and does the view template a blade file??

Comment: yes its a blade file.

Comment: then you have access to all public properties of the mailable class to the view file, or you can send data via the `with` method. and you can use them to change your content on the view file.

Comment: I was thinking of the same approach, although I was not sure. I'll try it and update if anything comes up.

Comment: sure, let me know if you want any more detail or example.

Comment: So I can modify the public properties but how do I actually change just the content of the blade file before building. I want to keep the blade file the same but provide a modified content using the blade file to the build function. Is there any way to do that? @zahidhasanemon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233879/discussion-between-aadesh-dhakal-and-zahid-hasan-emon).